# How do I put Arrays inside Arrays into ForEach in SwiftUI?

Tags: arrays, swiftui, foreach

I have following Code, however, I cant get the respective element to be shown.

```
struct MyUserView: View {

let Users = [
["name": "Manuelle", "age": 23, "profilePicture": Image(systemName: "person"), "status": "inactive", "icon": Image(systemName: "message.fill")],
    
["name": "Michael", "age": 39, "profilePicture": Image(systemName: "person"), "status": "active 12 minutes ago", "icon": Image(systemName: "square.on.square")]
]

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
ForEach(Users.indices, id:\.self) { user in
HStack {
Text(Data[user]["name"]!)
Image(UIImage(Data[user]["profilePicture"]!))
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many, many issues.

First create a struct `User` for the model, the members `profilePicture` and `icon` are declared as `String` rather than as a SwiftUI view.

```
struct User : Hashable {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
    let profilePicture, status, icon: String
}
```

In the view use the struct which is more comfortable for several reasons

```
struct MyUserView: View {
    
    let users = [
        User(name: "Manuelle", age: 23, profilePicture: "person", status: "inactive", icon: "message.fill"),
        User(name: "Michael", age: 39, profilePicture: "person", status: "active 12 minutes ago", icon: "square.on.square")
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(users, id: \.self) { user in
                    HStack {
                        Text(user.name)
                        Image(systemName: user.profilePicture)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I also put an individual View for each user to use as destination in navigationlink? it says that my struct: USer is Hashable- Error.

Comment: I don't understand. `User` **is** `Hashable`

Comment: Sorry, it says user does not conform to protocol "Hashable" with this second error message: "Protocol 'View' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements"

Comment: Please ask a new question and show the relevant code.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. I just posted the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72735722/type-user-does-not-conform-to-protocol-equatable-hashable