# "Type 'User' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'/ 'Hashable'

Tags: struct, swiftui

I want to add a variable of type View to my struct: User and then later add individual views to my users (as shown in Manuelle). However I get the error "Protocol 'View' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements" and "Type 'User' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'/ Hashable".

```
struct User : Hashable {
        let name: String
        let age: Int
        let profilePicture, status, icon: String
        let view: View
    }

struct MyUserView: View {
    
    let users = [
        User(name: "Manuelle", age: 23, profilePicture: "person", status: "inactive", icon: "message.fill", view: UserProfileView()),
        User(name: "Michael", age: 39, profilePicture: "person", status: "active 12 minutes ago", icon: "square.on.square")
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(users, id: \.self) { user in
                    HStack {
                        Text(user.name)
                        Image(systemName: user.profilePicture)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's bad idea. Keep model pure, and create views inside views per model conditions (if needed).

Comment: Okay, and what is your **question** about this result? Do you *understand* why the error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `let view: View` from the `User` struct, that's the main problem.

Also, you can't supply `id: \.self` to the `ForEach` view. `id` has to be a property that is a unique identifier of the struct it cannot be the struct itself because you'll get a crash when the array of structs changes. You have a few options to fix it:

```
ForEach(users, id: \.name) { user in
```

Or better:

```
struct User : Identifiable {
    var id: String {
        return name
    }
```

Because then you can simply do:

```
ForEach(users) { user in
```

But normally we do this:

```
struct User : Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
```

Unless of course the userID comes from a server.

Comment: *you can't supply id: \.self to the ForEach view*. You can, the framework calculates a hash value from the entire instance (like it does with simple conformance to `Hashable`). `\.name` Is dangerous if the values are not unique. The recommended way is indeed to adopt `Identifiable` and add an UUID property.